# Issue in servlet url mapping?

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc

```
    @PostMapping(path = "/images")  
    
    public void sendFiles( @RequestParam("transferFile")MultipartFile transferFile, @RequestParam("id") int id,  HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setContentType("application/images");
        try {
            String requestUrl="http://localhost:9090/NewFileHandling/file";
            URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
            HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
            
            

            OutputStream outputStream = httpCon.getOutputStream();
            byte[] data = transferFile.getBytes();
            
            outputStream.write(data);
            
            

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e);
            
        }    
    
    }
```

**in web.xml i have given DispatcherServlet **

error is
No mapping for POST /SpringProject/images
Kinldy help. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the context path of API?

Comment: And capture the HTTP request sent, including content-type.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not done the Controller level mapping.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/file")
```